# touch handling in cocos2d-x with many layers

Tags: c++, touch, cocos2d-x

I have a problem with cocos2d-x touch handler. I have two `CCLayers`. The first layer is the main application and the second one is a toolbox. The toolbox can slide over the first layer. main application has a special touch handling and the toolbox has touch handling too. When I slide down the toolbox and click on it, cocos2d-x runs the main application events and handlers. I want to run the toolbox handler functions when I click on it and I need to run main application handlers when I click on it too. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your  CCLayer toolbox, override function `registerWithTouchDispatcher()` to set the touch priority to be highest.

```
void ToolBoxLayer::registerWithTouchDispatcher()
{
    CCTouchDispatcher::sharedDispatcher()->addTargetedDelegate(this, numeric_limits <int> ::min(), true);
}
```